# dose-response curve - wrong x-line spacing

Tags: r, plot

I have a problem with the **dose-response curve** plot, because of the wrong x-line spacing between labels. How can I fix this problem?

code:

```
p<-mortB/n

y<-cbind(mortB, n-mortB)
m1<-glm(y~log(concent)*treatment, family=binomial)

plot(concent, p, type="n", log="x", xlab="Log(Concentration)", ylab="Mortality")
x<-seq(0,100,0.01)

lines(x, predict(m1, list(concent=x, treatment=factor(rep("B", length(x)), levels=levels(treatment))),type="response"))
```

plot:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ONJ9.png)

thx

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong x-line spacing"?  It looks okay to me.  The only problem is that you used the label `"Log(Concentration)"` and it should really be `"Concentration"` for consistency with the tick labels.

Comment: In the image with the plot, I see a bigger gap between labels 20-40 than between 80-100

Comment: That's because you asked for the x-axis to be on a log scale.